# Does a Meta Pixel custom event get tracked by all Pixel IDs on page?

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, facebook-pixel-helper

I'm working with a company that has multiple Meta pixels on their website. We've implemented the Leads event for a Meta Pixel to fire when any outbound link is clicked, however, we're also seeing it on page load for certain pages.

Basically, I'm wondering that is other Meta Pixels on the page are also using the standard Leads event, but for PageView, if that would mess with our intended trigger of link click. There's nowhere in the fbq('track', 'Leads') that allows you to specify the specific pixel.

I'm also thinking this, because when I click on an outbound link, I'm also getting a Purchase event, when no purchase event has been set up at all for our specific Meta Pixel.

I've looked at all the intended placements of the Meta Pixel, and while I'm always getting a Leads event when I click on Outbound links, I'm also getting it as a page load on one specific page. I don't have direct access to either the Facebook account where it's set up, or Google Tag Manager where the pixels were implemented, so I have limited capability to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be quite a mass.

Here is the code and document about how to specify the facebook pixel id in the fbq function

1. If you are using standard event, Like lead

```
 // only fire the Purchase event for Pixel A
  fbq('trackSingle', '<PIXEL_A>', 'Lead',{
    //optional parameters
  });
```

2. If you are using custom event, Like xxx_test

```
   // only fire the custom event Step4 for Pixel B
  fbq('trackSingleCustom', '<PIXEL_B>', 'Step4',{
    //optional parameters
  });
```

---

But this is only make sure you will not affect other's pixel.

If other vendor is using `fbq('track', "lead")`

Your pixel will still receive the event and maybe you don't want it.

In this case. You can only tell the company this situation and how to fix it by using `trackSingle`

---

[Document](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/v2/2017/11/28/event-tracking-with-multiple-pixels-tracksingle/)